# get count of print pages in html table

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, printing

I have a java project (IDE eclipse). There is a report shows data in  [Table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). Report is printed in *LEGAL Landscape* pages in web browser MOZILLA FIREFOX version 51.0. Since, this Web application uses digital signatures, so FIREFOX version is limited to 51.0 for compatibility.

I have to store the ***number of pages printed*** in database of every report.
In Report there is a column with more than 4000 characters, so estimating no. of rows will not work for me.

Is there any way to count number of pages *while printing* and store that counted value in database ??

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you read this [article by A List Apart](https://alistapart.com/article/boom)

```
@page front-matter :left {
@bottom-left {
  content: counter(page, lower-roman);
 }
 }
```

(this uses CSS3)